# Visual Studio 2017 Debugger.Launch() - Source not available

Tags: visual-studio-2017, entity-framework-core, asp.net-core-2.0

I am using ASP.Net Core 2 & EF Core 2. Trying to debug EF OnModelCreating(). I have following code:

```
if (!System.Diagnostics.Debugger.IsAttached)
   System.Diagnostics.Debugger.Launch();
```

Then in package manger I run the migration: **Add-Migration V1**, which breaks and ask which debugger to use and it ask whether i need to start a new VS 2017.

When it starts the new VS 2017, It says;

**Source not available**
- Source information is missing from the debug information for this module.

1. I have JIT enabled
2. Compiled as DEBUG
3. The same procedure I have followed previously in VS 2015 with an old .Net version and it works fine!

Has anyone experienced this before?

Comment: Use Process Monitor to see which EXE and DLL is loaded. Make sure it's really the new one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

coudln't get this to work with any of the methods I tried. Finally, lot of console.write saved me. But it still seems an issue of VS2017.